# How could python keep the library from old version without installing one more time

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have owned python 3.4 and I just installed python 3.7.

How could I import those library I have installed in the 3.4 without installing one more time for python 3.7?

Comment: One dirty way is to *copy-paste* `site-packages` folder from python3.4 to python3.7

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar it will be a really  a bad approach, better to download the new packages  for those libraies

Comment: @prashantrana yup as I said **dirty way** but it will do for most of the libraries and better approach will be to get `Anaconda` and have different versions of `Python` in it using `conda env`

Comment: A *slightly* less dirty approach would be to run `pip freeze >requirements.txt` in Python 3.4 and then `pip install -r requirements.txt` in 3.7.

Comment: @tripleee thanks for your advice, that meets my requirement.

Comment: @tripleee it's not dirty, but right approach to installing the package in new python environment without disturbing codebase

Comment: It's dirty in the sense that if something was pulled in as a dependency which is no longer required, you will nevertheless be installed again.